# Angular 2 ng2-charts and Chart.js fill label gabs in xAxis

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

Playing around in Chart.js and ng2-chart.
Trying to have a time xAxis with `max` and `min` and auto fill it with time labels between, and without having to fill it in the labels.

`labels = ["6.00","8.20","8.20","20.00"];`
With theese labels the xAxis gets gabs between `min` and first label(`6.00`) and last label(`20.00`) and `max`. 
 Having hard time figuring out if this is possible or not?

Just ask if anything is unclear.

[image]

Made a 
[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/N01lk5OiK6puZ880BAww?p=preview)
to show the problem.

I really appreciate any help.